# C# Run SetUp in console application first

Tags: c#, nunit

I created console application and I want to run my class, but this class inherited from base class, that has [SetUp] and [TearDown]. When I run my app, then base class is skipped. How can I fix it to run this app from base class? is it possible?

This is my console app:

```
private static void Main()
    {
        switch ("Test")
        {
            case "Test":
                new Upload().UploadTest("Testing");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

and my class:

```
public class Upload : BaseTest
{
   
    [TestCase("Test")]

    public void UploadTest(string jobName)
    {
            // todo something

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up a constructor and call ```base.SetUp``` etc?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you're just trying to run your NUnit tests, you should use an existing test runner, such as the [Visual Studio Test Adapter](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Index.html), ReSharper, or [the runners provided by NUnit](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Index.html). Or if you want to write code that is run using a console program and tested using NUnit, then you should have (at least) three classes: the console runner containing the Main method, the NUnit test, and the actual code you are running.